# Not able to create connection, pgadmin 3 with server in ubuntu

Tags: linux, postgresql, ubuntu

i am new to ubuntu. My problem is, can not able to connect Pgadmin with POSTGRES SERVER.

These are the steps which i followed to install server and Pgadmin,
1)To install postgres sql ->

```
"sudo apt-get install postgresql-contrib"
```

2)To Install Pgadmin ->

```
"sudo apt-get update"
"sudo apt-get upgrade"
"sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.4 pgadmin3"
```

While trying to connect pgadmin with server,

[connecting to server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iv39s.png)

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPmIL.png)

Comment: Why do you install _two_ postgresql servers? Or at least attempt to?

Comment: The error message shows that you do have a connection, but the authentication fails. Username or password are wrong or that user does not have access to that database you chose.

Comment: sry there is only one. it was a typing mistake

Comment: but i can access through the terminal with the same password and username

Comment: That would indicate a network issue, since a local connect uses the loopback device. I assume `pdadmin` and the postgresql server are on the same system?

Comment: yes on the same system

Comment: Please take a look into your servers log file to find out exactly if it is the connection or the authentication that fails.

Comment: when i search about installation steps of postgres sql. I sow that , creation of postgres repository. why should we create that?

Comment: No idea what you are trying to say with that. A "repository" was never mentioned, and log files have nothing to do with the installation.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have set the password for default user using

*sudo -u postgres psql postgres
enter  \password postgres in the terminal*

, if so try adding the following entry to pg_hba.conf

*host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5*

and then restart the postgres server